# Durable Function not returning large files

Tags: azure-functions, large-files, azure-durable-functions

I have a Durable Function (version 3) which returns an Excel sheet as base64 encoded text assigned to a property of a simple object like so:

```
string base64Encoded = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(reportContent);
log.LogInformation($"TrainingReport_Orchestrator: Tenant Id {ticket.Tenant}, base64Encoded.Length: {base64Encoded.Length}");
return new EnrollmentsReportResponse()
   {
    Success = true,
    ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
    Options = options,
    FileAsBase64 = base64Encoded
};
```

When the Excel file is very large, maybe > 80MB, it is not returned from the function. The log item (see code above) is shown in the log so the execution is past that point.

When I say "it is not returned", what I mean is: A check of the status of the function returns 202 and the check status location as if the function is still running.

Can anybody explain this and perhaps point to a solution?

Comment: Can you please provide more context regarding the code snippet you've shared? In particular, is that part of an Orchestrator Function, an Activity Function, or is this trigger by another Azure Functions Trigger? 

Also what type of hosting plan are you running on? Linux/Windows? Consumption/Premium/Dedicated? That would help me reason about what could be going on

Comment: Yes, of course. The snippet shown is the return statement from the Orchestrator function. It's running on Windows. As for the type (Consumption/Premium/Dedicated), could you please perhaps indicate where exactly I can see that?

Comment: you can know the functions app hosted plan from the overview page of your function in the portal as show in this image https://i.imgur.com/1MHFt5P.png. If the app service plan is with y1--> consumption plan, EP --> elastic premium plan, and all other plans like B1,s1,s2,s3,p1v2--> refer to dedicated app service plan